# How to use babel-plugin-styled-components with styled-components v6 in create-react-app

Tags: styled-components

In v5 I have been using `babel-plugin-macros` plugin along with `babel-plugin-styled-components` and in the code I used `styled-components/macro` import according to the instruction: https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#babel-macro. This will minify the class names in production without requiring me to update the babel config. In v6 macro is removed. I couldn't find updated instruction on how to use `babel-plugin-styled-components` in `create-react-app` to achieve the same functionality. Any idea?